# How to get TabItemEx items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following xaml

```
   <Grid Margin="5,0,5,0">
        <igWindows:XamTabControl Name="_xamTabControl"
             ItemsSource="{Binding AutoLogins}"
             Theme="Metro"
             AllowTabClosing="False"
             TabItemCloseButtonVisibility="WhenSelectedOrHotTracked"
             SelectionChanged="_xamTabControl_OnSelectionChanged">
            <igWindows:XamTabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type igWindows:TabItemEx}" BasedOn="{x:Static igThemes:PrimitivesMetro.TabItemEx}">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Server}" />
                </Style>
            </igWindows:XamTabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <igWindows:XamTabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <igDp:XamDataGrid DataSource="{Binding Logins}" IsGroupByAreaExpanded="False"
                                      GroupByAreaLocation="None" GroupByAreaMode="DefaultFieldLayoutOnly"
                                      RecordDeactivating="DataPresenterBase_OnRecordActivated">
                        <igDp:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
                            <igDp:FieldLayoutSettings AddNewRecordLocation="OnBottom" AllowAddNew="True" AllowDelete="True" />
                        </igDp:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
                        <igDp:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
                            <igDp:FieldSettings AllowResize="False" LabelWidth="200" LabelTextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </igDp:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
                    </igDp:XamDataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </igWindows:XamTabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </igWindows:XamTabControl>
```

How can I get here the TabItemEx items? Infragistics provide the [Utilities](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WPF/2011.1/CLR4.0/html/InfragisticsWPF4.v11.1~Infragistics.Windows.Utilities_members.html) class, but I can not find any useful methods to obtain the tabItemEx items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the tabs have been generated for the underlying items in `ItemsSource`, you can use either of the following methods:

```
_xamTabControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(object)
_xamTabControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(int)
```

The first accepts an item from the `ItemsSource` and returns the corresponding `TabItemEx`.  The second accepts the index of the item, i.e., its 0-based offset within the `ItemsSource` collection.